# using php mailer mail send from localhost xamp successfully but failed to sending in production windows hosting

Tags: php, windows, email, phpmailer

I have use PHP mailer for sending email 
in my localhost XAMPP server and email send successfully using following attached code script (using PHP mailer)
 but in Windows 2012 hosting in production server its show me error

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate
SMTP connect() failed.
```

this is my script

```
<?php

ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);

require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php');
require_once('PHPMailer-master/class.smtp.php');
$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->MailerDebug = true;
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;


/*$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->SMTPSecure = false;*/

$mail->Username = 'someusername@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';
$mail->setFrom('someusername@gmail.com', 'hello');
$mail->addAddress('testaddress@gmail.com');
$mail->addReplyTo('someusername@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'the subject of the e-mail';
$mail->Body = 'The body of the email';
//  $mail->AltBody = 'Alternative'; // this is mostly sent to your own mail

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: <pre>' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}


?>
```

error message
[image: click here]

I have also enable less security app option in google mail setting

Comment: Please don't post images of text, post the text instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're using an old version of PHPMailer, so [upgrade](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

There are messages and links in the error message that tell you about the problem, firstly on Google, and also a link to the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, which describes [exactly this problem in great detail](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#gmail-oauth2-and-allow-less-secure-apps). There's a reason those links are there.

When it says "Please log in via your web browser and then try again", it means exactly what it says: you should log into your gmail account using a normal web browser, and then try your script again. The reason for this is that google treats your web login as a means of confirming that your account is being accessed legitimately.

Follow the rest of what the guide says to do and it will fix your issue.

You also gave away your ID and password to your gmail account, so I suggest you change them.

Comment: i change my gmail account password, after mail send successfully

Answer (score -1):

this config works for me:

```
$mail->Host = 'smtp.googlemail.com';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
```

Comment: You need to say *why* you think this might work - though it won't, and has nothing to do with the reason for the failure.